# How to get container dimensions before compile?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

How do I ensure that a directive gets compiled after getting dimensions of the container it is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no plunker/fiddle provided, this is an another guess :)

Try putting the new element into DOM before compling like this:

```
var newelem = '<div d3-bars bar-height="20" bar-padding="5"></div>';
newelem = angular.element(newelem);
element.append(newelem);
$compile(newelem)(scope);
```

That is in order to allow the new element to have width and height before get compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, that you forgot to assign your `scope` variable. Just try `$scope` instead if you're in a controller.

Another possible apporach would be, to toggle a boolean variable with your button and use `ng-show` for your D3 code like this:

```
<button ng-click="showD3 = != showD3">Click me!</button>
<div d3-bars bar-height="20" bar-padding="5" ng-show="showD3"></div>
```